# an algorithm that works with an increasing number of variable(python)

Tags: python

i have made a database using 2d arrays to store the free periods each of my friends has at school(e.g. period 1 and 2 on monday would be ["monday",1,2])

the data is stored on an external python file so that it can be read from and written to.

the problem is that i do not know how code an algorithm that works automatically no matter if a new array has been added or one has been taken away.

here is my code:

```
exec(open("data.py").read()) 
free=[["monday"],["tuesday"],["wednesday"],["thursday"],["friday"]] 
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(7):
        if j in d[i] and j in k[i]:
            free[i].append(j)
    print(free[i])
```

and a sample data sheet

```
m=[[5,6],[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[1,2,3,4],[]]
d=[[],[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[1,2]]
k=[[1,2],[5,6],[3,4],[5,6],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: Note that `exec(open("data.py").read())` should be replaced by an `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using pre-named variables, it makes it difficult to adapt for larger-scale work. This could be fixed by using a dictionary:

```
friends = {"m": [[5,6],[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[1,2,3,4],[]],
           "d": [[],[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[1,2]],
           "k": [[1,2],[5,6],[3,4],[5,6],[1,2,3,4]]}
```

Make sure that all default executable code in the file `data.py` other than variables falls under `if __name__ == __main__` so that it does not run by default, and so that you can use:

```
import data

free = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"] 

for friend in data.friends:
    res = data.friends[friend]
    for i in range(5):
        res.insert(i, free[i])
    print(friend, ":", str(res))
```

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention a key part of my code, the idea was that i would output the common free periods (common numbers in each array) . for example: 
` 
friends{ "d": [[],[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[1,2]], "k": [[1,2],[5,6],[3,4],[5,6],[1,2,3,4]]}
 `
the output would be:
` 
[["monday"],["tuesday"],["wednesday,3,4],["thursday",5,6],["friday",1,2]]
 `
 or something similar 

p.s. i also realised there are no common free periods across 'd', 'm' and 'k' so please ignore the data for 'm'